# Spring integration fails on startup: InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

i recently forked [this repo](https://github.com/ali-bouali/spring-boot-3-jwt-security). Now I want to run integration tests, but i get a very weird exception. I have never seen this exception and I cannot find much information about it.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
> at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
> at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
> at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
> at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:110)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:90)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:85)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
> at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
> at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
> at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)

My testclass for the integration test is the following:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class Spring3jwtdemoApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

//  @LocalServerPort
//  private int randomServerPort;

  @Test
  public void contextLoads() {
    System.out.println("This should work");
  }

}
```

Do you have any ideas why this does not work? Help is very much appreciated. You can have a detailed look at the code [here](https://github.com/JakobHerk/Spring3jwtdemoApplication).

Also, if you are an expert you might want to look at the SecurityConfiguration class, there are some compile errors :D

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter
```

I had similar problem. Error above would appear before Groovy unit tests starts.
For me it was upgrade spock-spring dependency in pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
   <version>2.4-M1-groovy-3.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```